# Need to create adapter for List that I am getting from Api

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Right now I am getting movies from tmdb APi.

I want to get Reviews from their Endpoint.
http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference/movies/movieidreviews/get?console=1

Right now I am getting movies from Retrofit to my recycleview in MainActivity.
I have three model classes and interface.

I dont know how to create Adapter for review list.
After I create Adapter i need to call it in my DetailsActivity
Can somebody help me please?

**I am getting error on : 
public int getItemCount()**

This is my project github: https://github.com/adnxy/MyMovieApp

Here are my model classes, i wont write getters and setters here:

```
public class Reviews {
    @SerializedName("id_review")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("author_review")
    private String author;
    @SerializedName("content_review")
    private String content;
    @SerializedName("url_review")
    private String url;
```

Review result model class bellow:

```
public class ReviewResult {

private List<Reviews> reviewResults;

public List<Reviews> getReviewResults() {

    return reviewResults;
}
```

ReviewWraper without getters and setters bellow:

```
public class ReviewWraper {

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("page")
private int page;
@SerializedName("results")
private List<Reviews> results;
```

Bellow is my AdapterClass.
This is what i was trying to make, but it does not work.
I am getting error on : 
public int getItemCount()

```
public class ReviewAdapter {


private List<Reviews> rReviewList;
private LayoutInflater rInflater;
private Context rContext;

public ReviewAdapter(Context context, List<Reviews> rReviewList) {
    this.rContext = context;
    this.rReviewList = rReviewList;
    this.rInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public MovieDetailActivity.MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {

    View view = rInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_review, parent, false);




public void onBindViewHolder(MovieDetailActivity.MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {

            Reviews reviews = rReviewList.get(position);
            Picasso.with(rContext)
                    .load(reviews.getUrl())
                    .resize(342, 0)
                    .into(holder.imageView);
        }




        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return (rReviewList == null) ? 0 : rReviewList.size();
        }

        public void setReviewList (List<Reviews> reviewsList) {
            this.rReviewList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.rReviewList.addAll(reviewsList);

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        private void notifyDataSetChanged() {

        }
```

}

Comment: In your 'ReviewAdapter' constructor, you should have to pass one more parameter to get 'rReviewList'

Comment: Can you write which one and how? Thanks

Comment: That's not so hard.. wait.. I'll post that

Comment: what is this ?--> public MainActivity.MovieViewHolder
share your MainActivity code

Comment: I copy that from my MovieAdapter. Do i need to delete that or change it to DetailsActivity. But I am not passing any intent

Comment: I dint get.. please tell what exactly you want..

Comment: I am getting reviews from tmdb api in ListView.I need to create adapter that is going to show list of reviews with pictures of people and time they left review.

Comment: @Adnxy: Why You created MovieViewHolder inside MainActivity

Comment: Yes because I am getting movies inside recycleview of MainAcitivity. Do I need MovieViewHolder for my ReviewAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ReviewAdapter` class:

```
public class ReviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainActivity.MovieViewHolder> {

private List<Reviews> rReviewList;
private LayoutInflater rInflater;
private Context rContext;

public ReviewAdapter(Context context, List<Reviews> rReviewList) {
    this.rReviewList = rReviewList;
    this.rContext = context;
    this.rInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public MainActivity.MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View view = rInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_review, parent, false);
    return new MainActivity.MovieViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MainActivity.MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Reviews reviews = rReviewList.get(position);
    Picasso.with(rContext)
            .load(reviews.getUrl())
            .resize(342, 0)
            .into(holder.imageView);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Perform click
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return rReviewList.size();
}

//To update data
public void setReviewList(List<Reviews> reviewsList) {
    this.rReviewList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.rReviewList.addAll(reviewsList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I inflate my layout to row_review.xml? :))Thanks

Comment: Do I need to delete this part and do I need MovieHolder for my new list?: public MainActivity.MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View view = rInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_review, parent, false);
    final MainActivity.MovieViewHolder viewHolder = new MainActivity.MovieViewHolder(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: please have a look at edited answer. I have made an adapter for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you re such a good person:))                                        I am getting errors on  Override of onBindViewHolder ,getItemCount and setReviewList.

Comment: just make sure that 
ReviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainActivity.MovieViewHolder>
and if error still exist, then let me know the error

Comment: Should I set new ViewHolder in my DetailsActivity? That is place where i want to show my list?

Comment: Not recommended, but the good practice is to always make your ViewHolder inside the Adapter (specially for RecyclerView's Adapters), but if you want that to be inside MainActivity, you have to make that ViewHolder as 'static'

Comment: I have set new ViewHolder to my Details Activity and extended RecyclerView.Adapter(MovieDetailsAcitivity.MovieViewHolder>               in my Adapter class.  it says: getItemCount() is already defined in MoviesAdapter.ReviewAdapter   and getting error can not resolve variable v. It is inside return new MainActivity.MovieViewHolder(v);

Comment: just replace 'MainActivity.MovieViewHolder(v);' with 'MovieDetailsAcitivity.MovieViewHolder(v);'

Comment: I did it but still getting those errors v can not be resolved, and getItemCount

Comment: By mistake, I had created two getItemCount() just have a look at modified answer and remove one(extra) method

Comment: It should be 'view' instead of 'v'

Comment: Great, it is working right now. I have changed symbol v to view and it is working .I hope that is right.  I will just add Picasso for pictures.Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot bro!! I just want to ask you how to implement adapter inside DetailsAcitivity. Something like this:  rAdapter = new MoviesAdapter.ReviewAdapter(MovieDetailActivity.this);
        rRecyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);

Comment: It should be: 
----
(as I suggested for constructor)
rAdapter = new MoviesAdapter.ReviewAdapter(MovieDetailActivity.this, your_review_list); 
rRecyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);

-----
and if you're using setReviewList() method, then it'll be fine as:
rAdapter = new MoviesAdapter.ReviewAdapter(MovieDetailActivity.this); 
rRecyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);

Comment: Can not resolve symbol .ReviewAdapter . I already defined it  private MoviesAdapter.ReviewAdapter rAdapter;

Comment: I am using setReviewList() method

Comment: You can use implementation as you suggested. And just make that class public instead of private

Comment: public MoviesAdapter.ReviewAdapter rAdapter;  and .ReviewAdapter is still red. Maybe i need to move ReviewAdapter to another package?

Comment: rRecyclerView.setAdapter(rAdapter);   rAdapter is giving me error: setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.Recycleriew.Adapter) in RecyclerView cannot be applied to (MoviesAdapter.ReviewAdapter)

Comment: please push your code on GitHub, and just inform me. I'll have a look.

Comment: Nope, i will update it and write you when I do it.Need to make some changes and I will push it

Comment: but you can see, only change is in my ReviewAdapter, so you can see it from there.I just have problems with loading Adapter and ListView in my DetailActivity, so I can show it on DetailActivity xml. Thank you

Comment: I dont have 20 reputation, is it problem to add me on skype: a.sahinovic14  thanks

Comment: please retry.. in chat link.. ;)

Comment: Thanks, but can you create another chat? It again says I need 20 repuration. Or I will have to wait few mins

Comment: I have to wait for few mins, because it still says i need 20 reputation:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112388/discussion-between-meet-and-adnxy).